# What is the definition of $\operatorname{Fun}^{B \mathbb Z}$ used in Nikolaus--Scholze Proposition B.5?

Tags: homotopy-theory, equivariant-homotopy

I am trying to understand the relationship between cyclic objects in a quasicategory $\mathcal C$ and $S^1$-equivariant objects in $\mathcal C$ as presented in [Nikolaus--Scholze "On Topological Cyclic Homology,"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01799) Appendix B.

Specifically, I would like to understand Proposition B.5 and its proof, reproduced here:

> **Proposition B.5.** For any $\infty$-category $\mathcal C$ admitting geometric realizations of simplicial objects, there is a natural functor
>   $$ \operatorname{Fun}(N(\Lambda^{\operatorname{op}}), \mathcal C) \rightarrow \mathcal C^{B\mathbb T}$$
>   from cyclic objects in $\mathcal C$ to $\mathbb T$-equivariant objects in $\mathcal C$. The underlying object of $\mathcal C$ is given by
>   $$(F \colon N(\Lambda^{\operatorname{op}}) \to \mathcal C) \mapsto \operatorname{colim_{N(\Lambda^{\operatorname{op}})}}j^*F.$$
>
> *Proof.* The functor can be constructed as the composite
>   $$\operatorname{Fun}(N(\Lambda^{\mathrm{op}}), \mathcal{C}) \rightarrow \operatorname{Fun}^{B \mathbb{Z}}(N(\Lambda_{\infty}^{\mathrm{op}}), \mathcal{C}) \rightarrow \operatorname{Fun}^{B \mathbb{Z}}(\mathrm{pt}, \mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}^{B B \mathbb{Z}}=\mathcal{C}^{B \mathbb{T}}$$
>   Here, in the middle we use the $B\mathbb Z = \mathbb T$-equivariant functor 
>   $$ \operatorname{colim_{N(\Lambda_\infty^{\operatorname{op}})}} \colon \operatorname{Fun}(N(\Lambda_{\infty}^{\mathrm{op}}), \mathcal{C}) \rightarrow \mathcal C.$$
>   By Theorem B.3, the underlying functor to C is given by 
>   $\operatorname{colim}_{N\left(\Delta^{\operatorname{op}} \mathrm{P}\right)} j^{*}$, which also shows existence of the colimit.  $\square$

In this proposition,

- $\mathbb T$ is the circle group,
- $\Lambda$ is Connes' cyclic category and $\Lambda_\infty$ is the paracyclic category with $\Lambda_\infty/B\mathbb Z \simeq \Lambda$,
- $\mathcal C^{B\mathbb T}$ is the functor $\infty$-category $\operatorname{Fun}(B\mathbb T, \mathcal C)$.

Here are two specific questions I would like to know the answer to:

1. What is the definition of $\operatorname{Fun}^{B\mathbb Z}(X,Y)$? I think this is the only place in the paper where this notation shows up, and I haven't found a definition of it elsewhere. My guess is that these are supposed to be some sort of $\mathbb Z$-equivariant functors from $X$ to $Y$. For a while I thought this might be just functors under $B\mathbb Z$, but this doesn't quite add up.
2. Related to the first question, how do you show that $\operatorname{Fun}^{B \mathbb Z}(\operatorname{pt}, \mathcal C)$ is $\mathcal C^{BB\mathbb Z}$? I am definitely missing something here, because it seems to me that $\mathbb Z$-equivariant functors from a point to $\mathcal C$ should be some sort of $\mathbb Z$-equivariant objects in $\mathcal C$. Is this a general fact or something specific to $\mathbb T = S^1$?

Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, I found an answer to this question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322661/definition-of-fung-mathcal-c-mathcal-d-in-the-setting-of-quasicategories?rq=1

Sorry for the duplicate!